# Powershell command to Get all resources in V2 in azure subscriptions

Tags: powershell, azure

can some one help me how to get all V2 resources in a subsciption using powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Log into your Azure Subscription (`Add-AzureRmAccount`) and do:

```
Get-AzureRmResource
```

without any parameters. It will return the list of all resources in Azure Subscription.

Comment: I need only V2 resources. Above command returns V1(ASM) resources too..

Comment: well, filter them out, its not that hard. I don't have any v1 resource in my sub to test, if you show some v1 examples i can show an example to filter it out

Comment: Thank you. We can filter them by ResourceType. for example - V1 Vnets - Microsoft.ClassicNetwork/virtualNetworks, v2 vnets - Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. We can filter them by ResourceType. for example - V1 Vnets - Microsoft.ClassicNetwork/virtualNetworks, v2 vnets - Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks